# Можно ли обособлять наречие "равным образом"?

Tags: пунктуация

В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" сказано, что наречное выражение "равным образом" не обособляется, но вот в одном юридическом тексте оно выделено запятой:

"**Равным образом**, заявитель не имеет права ссылаться на факт и в случае, когда он знал об этом факте, но не понимал его значения. [К вопросу об основаниях для пересмотра по вновь открывшимся обстоятельствам решений, определений суда, вступивших в законную силу, предусмотренных ГПК РФ (2004) // «Арбитражный и гражданский процессы», 2004.05.24]

**Это ошибка или возможны какие-то исключения?**

Comment: Поскольку источник не указан, полагаю, вы просто неверно его интерпретировали. Остальное - в ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что это *ошибка*.
"Равным образом" относится к так называемым [**ложным вводным словам**](http://www.litsite.ru/2011/01/13/loznye-vvodnye-slova/) и не выделяется запятыми.

Статья  [**"Пунктуация документных текстов"**](http://www.myshared.ru/slide/263684/) в п.44 говорит о том же.
*Слова и обороты деловой речи, **не требующие** выделения знаками препинания:*
...приблизительно, **равным образом**, фактически, тем не менее, при всем (при) том...

Такая же ошибка (если ошибка!) обнаружилась, например, в [**Византийском временнике**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=t_rODAAAQBAJ&pg=PT288&lpg=PT288&dq=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=RlGPrARFPa&sig=_-E-4xaMvEMFxWlhieTPkfFEfTM&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirtfialPfUAhVGEpoKHehrBdcQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%20%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false) (институт Истории АН СССР):
*Равным образом, лучше (стр. 23) опираться на текст Лаврентьевской летописи в отношении событий 1084 г...*

Если заменить "равным образом" на один из синонимов (допустим, "также"), то станет понятно, что запятая все-таки не нужна.

Comment: *Если заменить "равным образом" на один из синонимов (допустим, "также")*  - ну какие же это синонимы?! Синонимом могло бы служить "аналогично", "точно так же". Но здесь и этого нет. См. мой ответ.

Comment: *Статья "Пунктуация документных текстов" в п.44 говорит о том же.* - а нельзя источник предъявить в исходном виде? Или хотя бы автора назвать?

Comment: ра́вным о́бразом, нареч. качеств.-обстоят. В равной степени; одинаково. Синонимы: в свой черед, в свою очередь, в таком же духе, в ту же линию, как и, на такой же манер, по образу и подобию, подобным же образом, равно как, так же, также, таким же макаром, таким же манером, таким же образом, тем же порядком, тоже. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/278927/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC

Answer (score 2):

> наречное выражение "равным образом" не обособляется, но вот в одном
> юридическом тексте оно выделено запятой:

Для применения этого правила (даже если считать его правильно воспроизведенным) необходимо как минимум удостоверится, что оборот является наречием, то есть членом предложения. Такое возможно, когда наличествует глагол, к которому оно относится: *"Соучастник преступления равным образом несет гражданскую ответственность"*.  Здесь могло бы стоять вместо "равным образом" что-то типа "аналогично", "равнозначимо" - и тогда это очевидно наречие.

Но в примерах-то (обоих, включая византийский) это чисто вводное сочетание, означающее отношение пишущего к событию.  Здесь трактовка как наречия просто меняла бы смысл документа.

"Равным образом, заявитель не имеет права ссылаться на факт" - заявитель не имеет права аналогично ссылаться на факт... - это вообще на грани абсурда.

Здесь речь не о том: "Эквивалентно описанному выше случаю" - а такой оборот вполне может обособляться.

Смотрите, какой чудесный пример из нацкорпуса.

> **Равным образом** надлежало бы определить и те места, где реки протекают из Белоруссии и впадают в реки пограничныя, дабы на устье
> оных определить разъездные суда, когда береговой объезщик чрез реку,
> текущую из нутра Белоруссии, переехать не может, таким образом
> предписанной денной и ночной разъезд безпрерывно производим быть
> может. [А. Н. Радищев. [О таможенных обрядах]

Да, старый стиль, но в одном случае, у одного автора - обособляется, в другом нет. Это не случайно, в первом случае возможно понимание как наречия (хотя и это не очевидно), во втором - нет.

> В следствие сего указа все внутренния таможни и заставы, **равным
> образом**, и бывшей при оных осмотр уничтожаются, почему и трудно или
> невозможно почти будет иметь присмотр за вывозом таковых товаров из
> тех губерний в Россию, и кажется будет для торговли отяготительным,
> когда уже помянутым указом внутренния досмотры товаров отменены, и
> городов тех губерний мещанам пожаловано преимущество пользоваться
> свободным внутренним торгом. (там же)

И аналогично.

> **Равным образом** гостю не дано было знать, что еще с детских лет она
> была наслышана о лошадях, поскольку ее отец Андрей Кириллович
> Приходько вел дела Епифана Коломийцева и его родни, наследников
> полтавского конезаводчика… впрочем, о подобных родственных связях
> теперь, в советские времена, предпочитали помалкивать. [А. Е.
> Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> **Равным образом,**
> Николау категорически возражал против того, чтобы в дело был введен
> кто-то третий, связник. [А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)] [омонимия не
> снята] ←…→

Ваш пример там тоже есть. И что, везде ошибки?! В последнем примере (Рекумчук), я бы, кстати, в обоих случаях обособил - по смыслу.

Comment: Да, если не ориентироваться на справочник, задача не кажется однозначной. Складывается впечатление, что обособление может зависеть от структуры предложения. Иногда оборот (преимущественно  в начале предложения)  напоминает вводное слово, в этом случае он похож на авторскую метку вида "таким образом, кроме того", то есть служит для оформления порядка мыслей. В других случаях это явное наречие, которое легко заменяется союзом ТАКЖЕ. Поэтому "никогда не говори никогда", вероятно, обособление может допускаться.

Comment: Кстати, наречие не всегда относится к глаголу, но может распространять предложение в целом (такие словоформы называют детерминантами), например: "По вечерам здесь бывают концерты".

Comment: Пример из Радищева неудачен. Там обособление, да. Но не по причине того, что это вводное (="таким (же) образом"), а как уточнение предущего. Это какое приложение получается, (если такой термин применим для наречий - сравните: "говорил он много, горячо и страстно, и считал себя хорошим оратором"). Ну или что-то аналогичное. С остальным - согласен.

Comment: @Sibylla здесь как-то не принято устраивать развернутые обсуждения в комментариях. Или я ошибаюсь? У меня тезис был очень простой. 1. Для применения "правила" нужно убедиться, что мы имеем дело с наречием. 2. В данном случае я полагаю, что конструкция "равным образом" наречием не является (так как не член предложения). Следовательно, запрета на обособление по упомянутому правилу быть не может. Дальше уже идут примеры, которые можно признать или отклонить, но вдаваться в какие-то экскурсы.

Comment: @Мимоходов "Пример из Радищева неудачен..." возможно. Хотя ваша версия тоже не бесспорна. "Приложения" - в это как-то не очень верится. Но по теме и двух других хватит.